# How to add a custom parser for a file type into MC viewer?

Tags: pipe, midnight-commander, viewer

When you press <kbd>F3</kbd> on a `.sqlite` file in midnight commander the Viewer shows the SQL dump of the file instead of the original binary, and <kbd>F8</kbd> can be used to switch between *parsed* and *raw* modes.

This behaviour is available for quite a few other file types, e.g. F3 on a `.zip` file will list the file contents, on a `.doc` file will pipe the file through `antiword`, `.pdf` gets piped through `pdftotext`  etc.

Is it possible to add your own parsers for custom file types?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. Take a look at `/etc/mc/mc.ext`: programs and file type associations are defined there. For example, here are associations for zip, sqlite and doc that you mentioned:

```
# sqlite3.db
type/^SQLite 3.x database
    Open=/usr/lib/mc/ext.d/misc.sh open sqlite
    View=%view{ascii} /usr/lib/mc/ext.d/misc.sh view sqlite

# zip
type/^([Zz][Ii][Pp])\ archive
    Open=%cd %p/uzip://
    View=%view{ascii} unzip -v %f

# Microsoft Word Document
regex/\.([Dd][oO][cCtT]|[Ww][rR][iI])$
    Open=(lowriter %f >/dev/null 2>&1 &)
    View=%view{ascii} antiword -t %f || catdoc -w %f || word2x -f text %f - || strings %f
```

You can read about `mc.ext` syntax in comments in the beginning of the file: https://github.com/MidnightCommander/mc/blob/master/misc/mc.ext.in.

Here is a relevant article: https://ubuntuincident.wordpress.com/2010/12/08/configure-mc-open-files/